# Cannot delete own post

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I have a couple questions I posted myself and I would like to delete and I am not able to. Partly because they are down voted so much. On other stack sites, I am able to delete my own post.

Update: I just joined anther new stack site, asked a question with one rep, then successfully deleted it. I just cannot do it on this site.

Comment: Some helpful advice I can give you is to make sure you put more details in your question. The question box is large for a reason. :) In general, if you describe the problem you're facing and the purpose of the question, it gives the community more context to understand your challenges. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

You cannot delete questions that have answers on them.  This is a Stack Exchange-wide rule.

*[Side question: why are you needing the delete tool so frequently, on more than one site?]*

Comment: Actually the rule is for upvoted answers, zero/negative vote answers don't seem to count for the check

Comment: I have a down voted answer that I need to delete. I am testing out the delete tool and thats "why I need the delete tool so frequently."

Comment: @crh225 Please don't post just to test.  If you need help knowing how the features work, search [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or here or go ahead and ask a question here.  Thanks!

Comment: I test posted after I could not delete my own post